# What were those lines in the opening shot of Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, object-identification

In *Rogue One*, after the words *A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....* appear on the screen, it immediately cuts to a shot of *mostly* empty space. I say *mostly* because there are some weird lines in the top right corner. I can't seem to find a screenshot, so I drew it from memory after seeing the film twice in theaters.

[image: my drawing of those weird lines]

**What are those lines?** We eventually see Krennic's shuttle fly by in the next shot and those lines are gone:

[image: my drawing of the next shot]

Comment: Planetary rings, though I'm not sure if they're the rings of [Lah'mu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lah%27mu) itself or if they belong to another planetary body.

Comment: Looks like a barcode.

Comment: The rings are partly in shadow which is what makes them look wierd; they seem to end abruptly but actually just go into shadow

Comment: Compare with this photo of Saturn's rings http://i2.cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150731120003-nasa-saturn-with-rings-large-169.jpg

Comment: I have to say that I immediately thought of planetary rings when I saw the photo.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Those were the rings of [Lah'mu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lah'mu), the planet on which Galen Erso was hiding.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Star Wars: Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide)</sup></sub>

This image from the film gives you a better view. As you can see, the rings themselves are partially shadowed, explaining their abrupt edges.

[image]

Comment: This can be vastly improved by explaining the shadows, per [user20310's](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152070/what-were-those-lines-in-the-opening-shot-of-rogue-one#comment393234_152070) and [DavidTheWin's](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152070/what-were-those-lines-in-the-opening-shot-of-rogue-one#comment393269_152070) comments.   I suggest including the real image of Saturn.